# How to modify context when calling onchange methods of virtual records?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, xml-rpc

I am creating a virtual record in order to apply to it the results of several *onchange* methods. The problem is that for one of this methods, I need to pass a specific context, but this results in losing the virtual record data.

This is the *onchange* method I am calling:

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_product_id_valued(self):
    _logger.critical('PRODUCT INSIDE ONCHANGE')
    _logger.critical(self.product_id)
```

The following lines work OK, I can create a virtual record of a stock move, and the logger prints the product OK:

```
virtual_move = self.env['stock.move'].new({
    ...
    'product_id': product.id,
    ...
})
virtual_move.onchange_product_id_valued()
```

However, the following lines do not work. When I use `with_context` to set a specific context, the virtual move attributes are all empty inside the `onchange` method, so the logger prints an empty recordset of `product.product`:

```
virtual_move2 = self.env['stock.move'].new({
    ...
    'product_id': product.id,
    ...
})
virtual_move2.with_context(
    partner_id=xxx,
    picking_type_id=yyy,
    date=zzz,
    pricelist_id=aaa,
    fiscal_position=bbb,
).onchange_product_id_valued()
```

Why is this happening and how can I send a specific context to the `onchange_product_id_valued` method without destroying virtual record data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is wondering how to solve this, the solution is to apply the specific context before executing `new()` method:

```
self = self.with_context(
    partner_id=xxx,
    picking_type_id=yyy,
    date=zzz,
    pricelist_id=aaa,
    fiscal_position=bbb,
)
virtual_move2 = self.env['stock.move'].new({
    ...
    'product_id': product.id,
    ...
})
virtual_move2.onchange_product_id_valued()
```